# NetBeans 8.0.1 intellisense for JSF EL stops working after adding Java abstract bean

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jsf-2

The intellisense feature on NetBeans no longer works after I create the following abstract bean:

```
public abstract class ListModelAbstract<T> {

    private transient ListDataModel<T> model;
    public abstract List<T> getListFromService();

    public ListDataModel<T> getModel() {
        if (model == null) {
            model = new ListDataModel<T>(getListFromService());
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

This class and its implementation are used in the EL of the following JSF page:

```xhtml
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="15">
    <p:dataTable value="#{exportsBean.model}" var="exp">
        <p:column headerText="Transaction ID: ">
            <h:outputText value="#{exp.expid}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Buyer Name:: ">
            <h:outputText value="#{exp.buyername}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The code compiles and runs without any problems but I just don't have intellisense for this particular application. The feature works fine on everything else so I'm guessing that I need to do some special configuration?

I read some of the NetBeans documentation and did some online research but I can't find how to properly configure intellisense. I tried adding comments within the class (as above), but this did not help. I also cleaned the server cache and restarted the NetBeans without success. Does anybody have any idea why intellisense is not working for this particular application and what I can do to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Does the IDE show any error/s on the tray? Check to see, if there is an error or exception from underlying APIs like Swing/AWT upon pressing CTRL + SPACE.

Comment: Thanks Tiny. There are no compile time errors and no runtime errors. Just warnings on the JSF that the properties of the abstract bean are unknown.

Comment: I also deleted the Netbeans cache but still not working

Comment: Exceptions may have been thrown by the IDE itself as soon as CTRL + SPACE is hit which can be seen on the IDEs tray at the bottom right corner of the window occupied by the IDE something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pel6S.png). Ignore that specific balloon. There are 6 errors indicated by red colour. Your application may not be responsible in that case.

Comment: Yep. I can only messages for updates but no exceptions at all